# Simple node to node routing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, routing

I have this project wherein I should be able to display the route from one child node towards a parent node in QGIS. Attached is a simple photo to demonstrate my question:

[image]

The specifications are as follows:

1. The path from a child to a parent is always unique (for example: route from child 1 to parent node = Line 1B -> Line BA -> Line AP)
2. The nodes and the lines are separate shapefiles

So here's my question:

a. Can this be done by a query statement without having to rely to a plugin?

b. If this is not possible, what plugin should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try RoadGraph plugin/Network analysis library.

If you have two layers (they should be properly snapped):

1. Set some settings

[image]

2. Select point Start and Stop
3. Calculate

[image]

This plugin is based on a library that can be used to run queries programmatically. I don't know if English manual for it exists, here is [Google Translated description](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fgis-lab.info%2Fqa%2Fqgis-network-analysis-lib.html&edit-text=) of this library with code samples from it's author, Sergey Yakushev.